# Font change in a Salesforce form

Tags: html

I am looking to change the font of the tags/writing in a form that I am trying to put into my company's website. It doesn't seem to follow the format that I have seen for other HTML forms, and I have little experience coding in HTML. Any help would be appreciated. I do have the form action stuff in my original code, and the form works fine, I just need to change the font. adding font-family: "Helvetica" didn't do anything when put after the id=

```html
<label for="first_name">First Name</label><input  id="first_name"
maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input  id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="title">Title</label><input  id="title" maxlength="40" name="title" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="company">Company</label><input  id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="state">State/Province</label><input  id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="country">Country</label><input  id="country" maxlength="40" name="country" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit"
```

Comment: I copied your code and tried to do the same. It works fine for me. font-family: "Helvetica" worked fine. May be something is wrong with your browser. Sometimes that kind of things happen as well. Please add your css code too.

Comment: Are you targeting the labels? or ids inside the inputs? I you just want to change the labels text then do label{font-family: Helvetica; }

Comment: OK, maybe the problem comes from the fact that I am entering the code into Wix. Thanks!

Comment: And...do you have 'Hevetica' font installed on your computer???

Comment: ok I fixed it by adding style= "font-family: Helvetica;" inside the label. Like <label for="first_name" style= "font-family: Helvetica;" >. I think that that is what you were trying to say Julian, but I didn't understand based on that I have next to no coding experience outside some Python. Thanks yall!

Comment: Two last things. One, I don't think I have any CSS file, and 2, does anyone know an easy way to put a bit of spacing between the lines, so everything isn't smashed together?

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Gabe that is using the inline styles (they are "in-the-same-line" as the html element) The other approach which Julian mentions is for external styles sheets or styles applied within a style element which is within the  element like this :

```
   <head> 
...Some other stuff here...
     <style>
     label {font-family: Helvetica}
     </style>
   </head>
```